# Parenthesis after a slice in go?

Tags: go, slice

I've recently started learning go, and following through a [tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/). In the tutorial there is the line:

```
p1 := &Page{Title: "TestPage", Body: []byte("This is a sample Page.")}
```

They have a slice with parenthesis defined:

```
[]byte("This is a sample Page.")
```

However from all the docs I've read I've never seen parenthesis after a slice. I've only seen the format:

```
b := []byte{'g', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g'}
```

Using the curly braces. What is the role of the parenthesis?

Comment: That is definitely a special case for `byte`. I'm not sure how it is implemented but if you try something like that with other types it won't compile. Once I track down the actual implementation or spec I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the spec;

> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.
>
> ```
> []byte("hellø")   // []byte{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'}
> []byte("")        // []byte{}
>
> MyBytes("hellø")  // []byte{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'}
> ```

Check out the full conversion rules here; https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Based upon that, while the two lines of code result in the same behavior they are actually exercising completely unrelated language features. In the `[]byte{'l', 'o', 'l'}` case you're simply using composite literal syntax for initilization and this will always work with any types. In the other case a conversion is occurring, and beyond that it's a special case for strings. It happens to look much more like a constuctor is being called (thus making it a substitute for the composite literal syntax) but that is just coincidence.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that. That's very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @AR7 great questions, my pleasure to answer them. I'm going to update because I had a minor epiphany about what the code actually is.